# How do I make a raw sql query in EF Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working with a dotnet core 2.x application.

We've got a bunch of "code first" entities, and a DBSet for each in the DBContext.

EXAMPLE:

```
public class MyContext : DBContext
{
  public MyContext(DBContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base (options) {}

  public DbSet<Models.MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }
  ...
```

So far, so good.  Now I'd like to make this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyColumn from dbo.MyTable
```

Should be easy, right?  "Classic EF" had `dbData.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>`, but in EF Core 2.x I *should* be able to do something like this:

```
var myList = _context.MyTable.FromSql("SELECT DISTINCT MyColumn from dbo.MyTable").ToList();
```

This fails:

> ERROR CS1061: DbSet does not contain a definition for FromSql...

I read that maybe I needed to install an additional package, "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational".  But NuGet > Browse only showed me v3.1 (no 2.x versions) ... and installing this package wanted to bring in many, many other dependencies (!)

**QUESTION**:

Is there any way to make a simple SQL query with EF Core 2.x ...

... that *DOESN'T* require "select *" (bringing in the whole table!) and *DOESN'T* require downloading and installing a bunch of additional NuGet dependencies?

Comment: Well, there is no equivalent of EF6 `SqlQuery<T>`. `FromSql` requires defining query type containing the returned columns. There are 2.x Relational package, for instance [2.2.6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/2.2.6).

Comment: But you don't need raw SQL for such simple queries, LINQ is enough, `var myList = _context.MyTable.Select(e => e.MyColumn).Distinct().ToList();` will generate and execute the exact same SQL w/o the need of additional packages/types.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: 1) I later found the 2.2.x Relational packages on the NuGet web page (I don't know why "NuGet Browse" didn't show them).  I was pleased that there *weren't* "a million dependencies".  2) You're correct about FromSql needing a defined query type: I ran into that problem, and haven't figured out exactly how best to deal with it yet.  3) I'll try the LINQ.  It sounds like a good suggestion - thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per the comment from Ivan Stoev, the solution was to use a LINQ "Select":

```
var myList = _context.MyTable.Select(e => e.MyColumn).Distinct().ToList();
```

This worked well, and it does not require any external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want is `FromSqlRaw`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

in any case, If you're in EF, you shouldn't need to do that for such a simple query.  EF select does NOT require you to get the data from the entire table schema.  You can specify with a .select the exact columns you want.

see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/select-specific-columns-entity-framework-query/ for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, 1) `FromSqlRaw` is for EF 3.x (which also deprecates "FromSql").  I actually tried it, though - and got the same "CS1061" compile error.  2) The snippet you cited is for "EF Classic"; I don't think it will work in EF Core.  That's because its DBContext uses a no-args constructor ... and EF Core wants a DBContext constructor that injects `DBContextOptions`.  But thank you anyway :)

Comment: We've used .select in ef core.  The .select definitely allows you to pick columns.  I talked to our guy that did this, and he said to get .fromsql to work he actually had to create a db set for it.

Comment: You're correct.  I abandoned FromSql (now called "FromSqlRaw" in EF 3.x).  For several annoying reasons: a) I had to introduce an extraneous dependency,  b) I also had to define an extraneous DbSet, and finally c) that, in turn, meant defining a completely unnecessary model.  Geez!  EF Core doesn't make using a  SqlReader any easier The solution, as you said, was a LINQ Select().  Thanks to  Ivan Stoev for pointing me in the right direction!